# How to export PDF from Word to a specific directory?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

I know how to export PDF from Word. I always export the PDFs to one direction, with the name is same as the Word name. Is there any way to do this quickly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Try using the Adobe PDF Printer.  Then you can name it however you want and select the directory to save to.